# The first character is cut off when BufferedReader is used

Tags: java, file-io

This is the code :

```
File file = new File("Hello.txt");
file.createNewFile();
FileWriter write = new FileWriter(file);
BufferedWriter bufWrite = new BufferedWriter(write);
bufWrite.write("HelloWorld");
bufWrite.flush();
bufWrite.close();

FileReader read = new FileReader(file);
BufferedReader bufRead = new BufferedReader(read);
while(bufRead.read()!=-1){
 System.out.println(bufRead.readLine());
}
bufRead.close();
```

Here, the output is elloWorld. 'H'is not there. Why is it so?
Not sure if I'm doing anything wrong here!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's a surprising common question.

When you do

```
bufRead.read()
```

you actually read a character, it doesn't put it back and let you read it again later.

The simplest solution is to not do this.

```
File file = new File("Hello.txt");
try (PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(file))) {
    pw.println("HelloWorld"); // should have a new line
}

try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
    for (String line; (line = br.readLine()) != null; ) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
}
```

Comment: +1: Try with resources, and keeping the scope of `line` where it belongs. This is how it's done.

Answer (score 12):

Look at your loop:

```
while(bufRead.read()!=-1){
 System.out.println(bufRead.readLine());
}
```

You're using `read` in the loop - which will consume the first character of the next line.

You should use:

```
String line;
while ((line = bufRead.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

Comment: Suggest you use a for loop to declare the `String line` as in my answer.

Comment: @PeterLawrey: I can see the attraction in terms of reducing the scope, but I prefer the `while` loop in general I'm afraid. It feels a bit less alien to me.

Answer (score 3):

That has a very simple reason: The line

```
while(bufRead.read()!=-1){
```

consumes one character from the input stream. From [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Reader.html#read%28%29):

```
Reads a single character. This method will block until a character is available, an I/O error occurs, or the end of the stream is reached.
```

Answer (score 2):

You already read a character at

```
while(bufRead.read()!=-1)
```

**If there are more than one lines then it will vanish first character of every line!**

so use

```
String line;
while ((line = bufRead.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

See [read()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#read%28%29) [readLine()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine%28%29)

Answer (score 0):

`bufRead.read()` reads the first char.

Do `bufRead.ready()` instead.

Comment: No. `ready()` tells you whether there is data to read *without blocking,* which isn't the same thing as whether there is data to read. OP only needs to call `readLine()` here.